# Convergence of $ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{1\over n\log(n!)} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{1\over n\log(n!)} $$

I want to know whether the above converges...

I have no idea how to solve this question...

Please help...

Comment: Lower bound $\log(n!)$ using Stirling's formula, then use a comparison test.

Comment: You can bound $n! \geq (\frac{n}{2})^{n/2}$ then you should be able to compare your sum with $\sum_{i=1}^\infty 1/i^2$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Get an upper bound (for a direct comparison test) using the fact that $n! > e^n$ for sufficiently large $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\ln n! =\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln k.$ Now, roughly speaking, $n/2$  of those summands are $\ge \ln (n/2).$ Thus $$\ln n! \ge (n/2)\ln(n/2).$$

Comment: (+1) for the 1 second victory.  In a 100 meter dash, that is substantive.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

Note that $n!\ge \left(\frac n2\right)^{n/2}$.  Hence, $\log(n!)\ge \frac{n}{2}\log(n/2)>\frac{n}{2}$.

Comment: I beat you by 1 second. Let's leave both answers up.

Comment: @zhw. It can't be a case of great minds here ... mine is so far from great that it is sad.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to given you the best answer I can.  -Mark